# What repos should I enable in yum in order to install R in my computer (running elementaryOS)?

Tags: yum, elementary-os

I'm trying to install R in my computer (running elementaryOS) and I'm fairly new to this whole Linux thing.

When I run `sudo apt-get install r-base` I get R version 3.4.4, and I need version 3.6.1 - the lastest stable release. I downloaded R's source files directly from CRAN, `cd` my way into the folder where R`s source files are and ran `sudo ./configure`. I got this error message:

```
--with-x=yes (default) and X11 headers/libs are not available
```

Which then led to me a post in which the solution to this problem was to run:

```
yum install xorg-x11-server-devel libX11-devel libXt-devel
```

And now I get an error message saying I should enable repos for yum. This sounds very cryptic to me, I don't know what to do at all and googling "yum repos" didn't help me much either because there's an entire lingo I'm unfamiliar with, so I came here.

Comment: Which command did you run in the first place to get the error?  Could you copy-paste the exact error?

Comment: it was poorly formatted, my bad

Comment: I would swear elementary does not use yum e.g. It is Ubuntu based.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify: i) why you are attempting to install from source instead of using the version of R available for your distribution, ii) why you're using `yum` on elementaryOS instead of `apt-get` and iii) the _exact_ error you received.  Also, never run `configure` scripts with `sudo`!

Comment: Because sudo apt-get install r-base gives me an outdated version of R, so I need to install the latest from source. I`m using yum because I thought it solved the problem. I just want to install R and if you have a solution without yum I'd appreciate it.

Comment: I think you can use the Ubuntu version fitting your Elementary OS version: https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-r-on-ubuntu-18-04/

Comment: If you REALLY need to install from source, do `sudo apt-get install build-essential checkinstall` first. It will install the tools  you need to actually `make` and `checkinstall make install`after `configure`.  The 'checkinstall' command generates a debian-package you can install, instead of manually writing files all over your system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elementary uses `apt`, not `yum`. To build R from source, you need `libxt-dev`:

```
sudo apt install libxt-dev
```